# Excel formula returning different results on different machines

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

For a piece of work I'm doing, I use a formula that calculates the difference between two dates for each row in the report that the system generates. Essentially, the software I'm using generates the report and my formulas/logic are performed on the original report, going row by row, to create a second report.

However, the final result for one of my formulas seems to be different on my client's machine - whereas the formula (below) might generate '10' for me, i.e. 10 months, it will generate 11 on their machine. This was using DATEDIF as below:

=DATEDIF("E"&row(),"F"&row(),"M")

This would, in every row, perform the function and calculate the difference. I thought it might relate to DATEDIF, and so I changed how it worked so that it simply subtracted months (using MONTH formula), which again worked for me, but this time brought out "12" for the client.

Has anybody seen this before?

Comment: I don't understand, do you mean that "you created a file, inserted the formula, saved, sent file to client, clients opens it, and the result is different!" or your scenario is different?

Comment: Essentially, yes. In simple terms, I open the file and it brings out, let's say "10" as the answer to the formula, the client opens the exact same file from the same source and it brings out a different result - i.e. 11.

Comment: does he use a different calendar from yours, I only stumbled upon something similar because a client used 'Hijri' calendar. after all, you are talking about a 'month' difference between two machines, not a day but a hole MONTH

Comment: Sometimes I meet similar problems when I import data to excel from .csv / .txt as excel might recognize dates differently depending on regional settings. So I'd have a closer look on the date format of the original reports from both machines.

Comment: Check regional settings on the client machine